# как представить значение в словре в int

Tags: python

```
names = {
"katya": {
    "age": 21,
    "height": 50,
    "gender": "famale",
},
"tanya": {
    "age": 17,
    "height": 40,
    "gender": "famale",
},
"petya": {
    "age": 22,
    "height": 40,
    "gender": "male",
},
"stepa": {
    "age": 16,
    "height": 50,
    "gender": "male",
},
} 

for name in names:
    if name["age"] >= 18:
        print("можно")
    if name["age"] < 18:
        print("нельзя")
```

выводится
string indices must be integers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переменная `name` будет проходиться по ключам словаря, в данном случае по строкам.
Поэтому к элементам стоит обращаться так:

```
for name in names:
    if names[name]["age"] >= 18:
        print("можно")
    else:
        print("нельзя")
```